# Are many to many relationships absolutely neccessary in this case?

Tags: mysql, database-design, cakephp

I have the following models: Asset and User
Assets belongsTo User
User hasMany Assets

A Simple database model would look like this

```
USER
id
name


ASSET
id
name
user_id
```

Now the question is really about a download table to model the fact that users can download many assets and assets can be downloaded by many users.

In cakePHP, it would be a users_assets table with a simple model like this:

```
USERS_ASSETS (alias Downloads)
id
user_id
asset_id
```

But this is confusing because if you use cake's bake feature, you'll have to assign
more than one relationship between users and assets, the relationships described above and the new HABTM relationship: i.e.:

```
assets belongsTo Users | users hasMany assets
assets hasAndBelongsToMany user | users hasAndBelongsToMany assets
```

Why can't I just have a table called downloads with the relationships:

```
user belongsTo downloads | downloads hasMany Users
asset belongsTo downloads| downloads hasMany Assets

DOWNLOADS:
id
user_id
asset_id
```

I guess I'm not sure if it's ok to have more than one relationship defined for a given set of models.

Which is the best option and why--using the users_assets table with an alias of downloads to let cake know of the HABTM relationship. Or is it better to use a table named downloads without the HABTM relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I'd create a separate download model and have "user hasmany downloads" "downlload belongsto user", "download belongsto asset", and "asset hasmany downloads". That's what the habtm means anyway. That way the download model can have other interesting data, like the date and time of the download. I wouldn't bother with a habtm relation unless you need to access the list of assets downloaded by a user in a really simple manner and don't really care about the linking table.By the way the linking table can be called anything you want, you can call itndownloads and still go with the habtm way of doing things.

As to your other question, yes you can have multiple relations with a model. You just have to use different keys. For example an asset can "belong to" an owner, which is a user, and also "belong to" an editor which is a different user.